# Basic stylesheet customization of "Text" cells not working for me

Tags: text, stylesheet

I have learned much from other posts about stylesheet customization.  Here is my procedure: Step 1 - Open a new, empty document.  Step 2 - Format..Edit Stylesheet.  I have added the following customizations to Text cells.

[image: My attempted customization of Text cells]

Step 3 - Install this customization as Test1.  Step 4 - Format..Stylesheet..Test1

The result is shown here

[image: Changing styles with my syntax works for Style but not for StyleData]

I understand the examples I've read, and believe the above should work.  If anyone can point out the error of my ways I would be most appreciative.  Is it syntax?

Comment: Could my problem be related to the fact that I am using the Home Edition?

Comment: For me it works. What happens if you simply leave out step 3 and 4? As far as I know, it should work for the Home Edition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Stylesheets must be provided with StyleData in the `CellExpression` rather than the `CellContents`.

The `CellExpression` for a cell is shown by pressing Cmd+Shift+E (Ctrl+Shift+E) with a cell bracket highlighted.

Frustratingly, a cell must be created in the Stylesheet before the `CellExpression` can be tampered with. This is the process you must go through:

1) Open stylesheet

[image]

2) Create a new cell

[image]

3) Expose the `CellExpression` of the cell

[image]

4) Provide the StyleData

[image]

5) Return the cell to its generated form - *some** changes aren't applied if the cell remains in its `CellExpression` form.

[image]

*I'd like to better understand why this is but I don't.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have it working now.  I had seen the instructions for accessing the CellExpression via keystrokes, but all those examples were Windows based and only mentioned Ctrl+Shift+E, but I am on a Mac.  Hats off!

Comment: As an alternative to using ShowExpression and manually typing new options you can click on the cell bracket and set the style data via the options inspector.